# Flutter onboarding slider package

Tags: flutter

I'm new to learning flutter and I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask questions about packages but I have made an app using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_onboarding_slider. When the last screen appears the indicators from below are not visible as I have no need of a floating button and have set it to false. How do I fix it? Here's the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_onboarding_slider/flutter_onboarding_slider.dart';

class OnBoradingPackage extends StatefulWidget {
  const OnBoradingPackage({super.key});

  @override
  State<OnBoradingPackage> createState() => _OnBoradingPackageState();
}

class _OnBoradingPackageState extends State<OnBoradingPackage> {
  final List<Widget> bgWidgets = const [
    PageWidget(color: Colors.red),
    PageWidget(color: Colors.green),
    PageWidget(color: Colors.yellow),
    PageWidget(color: Colors.blue),
  ];

  final List<String> imgList = [
    'assets/1.jpg',
    'assets/2.jpg',
    'assets/3.jpg',
    'assets/4.jpg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Package'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        top: true,
        bottom: false,
        child: OnBoardingSlider(
          totalPage: 4,
          headerBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          background: bgWidgets,
          speed: 0,
          pageBodies: [for (var img in imgList) Image.asset(img)],
          hasFloatingButton: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PageWidget({super.key, required this.color});

  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
    );
  }
}
```

Package and version - flutter_onboarding_slider: 1.0.9

PS: I have raised an issue on their github repository.

Link: https://github.com/appinioGmbH/flutter_packages/issues/117

Comment: Could you also add the github issue link?

Comment: https://github.com/appinioGmbH/flutter_packages/issues/117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They developed it this way

this is the code from the plugin

```
currentPage == totalPage - 1
        ? SizedBox.shrink()
        : Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: _buildPageIndicator(context),
            ),
          );
```

if the page is the last page it will hide the page indicator because they thought that it will be the end of the intro screens (you can check the videos on the plugin page and its the same [flutter_onboarding_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_onboarding_slider)).

you can try to develop it using [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) instead without using the plugin

Comment: I did not know that widget existed. Works perfectly!